# Jfrog Artifactory High availability and maintenance

Tags: artifactory, jfrog-cli, jfrog-xray

We are using Jfrog artifactory selfhosted instance with license for our project and many customers are using for thir package and binary management.
Since this is hosted i our private selfhosted environments over linux platform, regularly we may need to have a maintenance window atleast 2 times in a month to apply patches to our servers and all. So we are considering for high availability for our currently running Jfrog instance which should resolve this downtime during the maintenance. Also we are looking for some better managemental scenarios as below and couldnt find any helpful guidance from the docs.

- How the Jfrog server insance service status can be monitored along with auto restart if the service is in failed state after the server reboot.
- Is there any way to set and populate a notification messsage to the sustomers regarding the sceduled maintenance.
- How can we enable the high availability for JFrog Artifactory and Xray. ?

Answer (score 1):

Here are some of the workaround you can follow to mitigate the situation

1. To monitor the health of the JFrog services you can use the below rest API

> curl -u : -XGET
> http://<Art_IP>:8046/router/api/v1/topology/health -H 'Content-Type:
> application/json'

If you are looking for a more lightweight check you can use

> curl -u: -XGET
> http://<Art_IP>:8081/artifactory/api/system/ping

By default, the systemctl scripts check for the availability of the services and restart them when they see a failure. The same applies to the system restart as well.

2. There is no option for a pop-up message however, you can set a custom message as a banner in the Artifactory. Navigate to Administration -> General settings -> Customer message. Here is the [wiki link](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/General+System+Settings#GeneralSystemSettings-CustomMessage)

3. When you add another node to the mix, Artifactory/Xray becomes a cluster to balance the load (or as a failover) however it is the responsibility of the load balancer/Reverse proxy to manage the traffic between the cluster nodes according to the availability of the backend node.